# Pause in second Itemize doesn't work like first one

Tags: beamer, itemize, pause

In the next MWE I created, I don't understand why Item 2.2 is not paused like Item 1.2. I think I am missing something but I don't know what!

[image]

```
\documentclass[fleqn,xcolor={dvipsnames,table}]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

% Thème CambridgeUS
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
  \usecolortheme{rose}
    \setbeamercovered{transparent}

\setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[circle]
\setbeamertemplate{itemize subitem}[circle]
\setbeamercolor{itemize item}{fg = darkred}
\setbeamercolor{itemize subitem}{fg = darkred}
\setbeamercolor*{block title}{fg=darkred!90,
bg= blue!5}
\setbeamercolor*{block title example}{fg=violet!90,
bg= darkred!5}
\setbeamercolor{section in toc}{fg=black}
\setbeamercolor*{title}{bg=blue!5,fg=darkred}
\setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{fg=white}
\setbeamertemplate{enumerate items}[default]
% \setbeamercolor*{enumerate item}{fg=darkred}
\setbeamercolor{local structure}{fg=darkred}

\begin{document}

  \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Some Title}

    \begin{minipage}[c]{.55\linewidth}
      \begin{center}
        Some figure
      \end{center}
    \end{minipage} \hfill

    \begin{minipage}[c]{.43\linewidth}
    \begin{center}
      \only<1-2>{
        \begin{itemize}[<+->]
          \vfill \item Item 1.1
          \vfill \item Item 1.2
        \end{itemize}
      }
      \only<3-4>{
        \begin{itemize}[<+->]
            \vfill \item Item 2.1
            \vfill \item Item 2.2
        \end{itemize}
        }
    \end{center}
    \end{minipage}
  \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure of the exact reason, but when beamer encountered your second set of `<+->` autoincrement specifications, it starts counting from 1 again. (May be it is because you wrapped the first set inside `\only`.)

In any case, you can do some arithmetic yourself and replace the second time by `<+(2)->` and then it works as expected.

```
    \only<3-4>{
    \begin{itemize}[<+(2)->]
        \vfill \item Item 2.1
        \vfill \item Item 2.2
    \end{itemize}
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, I would not have found by myself!